# detect how many pixles the cursor is away from the center of the screen

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to detect how many detect how many pixels the cursor is away from the center of the window.

Adding the returned value to a `var` using javascript or jQuery?.

Even better, if this could be attached to an element. So the `var` updates as you move and your mouse closer and further away from the elements centre point.

I'm not even sure this is possible hence why there is no code. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you want? attach onmousemove event to window and use window height&width subtracting current mouse position?

```js
var disFromCenterX = 0,
    disFromCenterY = 0
window.onmousemove = function(e) {
  disFromCenterX = Math.abs(window.innerWidth/2 - e.pageX);
  disFromCenterY = Math.abs(window.innerHeight/2 - e.pageY);
  console.log("distance from center x: " + disFromCenterX);
  console.log("distance from center y: " + disFromCenterY);
}
```

same logic on element

```js
var disFromCenterX = 0,
   disFromCenterY = 0
document.querySelector("#div").onmousemove = function(e) {
  var rect = this.getBoundingClientRect();
  disFromCenterX = Math.abs(this.clientWidth/2 - (e.pageX - rect.left));
  disFromCenterY = Math.abs(this.clientHeight/2 - (e.pageY - rect.top));
  console.log("distance from center x: " + disFromCenterX);
  console.log("distance from center y: " + disFromCenterY);
}
```

```css
#div {
  height: 400px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="div"></div>
```

Comment: Couldn't of asked for a better answer, this is perfect. Thank you mate!

Comment: Could you help with the same logic but on an block element?

Comment: i edited my answer to include that, there are better ways of doing it, this is just how i would approach this

Comment: i like your approach, it seems light weight and logic. Thank you again this is a real help.

Comment: light weight and fast* i mean